# Menu image alignment

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

As you can see  from http://calgarydefencelaw.com/, the image in the menu appears ok till 'BIO', then in the areas of 'law', it is down by one pixel.

Can anyone help why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have varying picture heights in the menu. The first two menu items are 65px high while the other three are 64px. Making them all the same height should solve this.

Comment: and it looks like the 1px that they are missing is a row of white on the bottom.  put that in and it should bump them up.